# .toml not reading

Tags: stellar-laboratory

I have added .toml files and CORS also enabled
The .toml file path is

```
https://URL/.well-known/stellar.toml
```

I have added home domain as well.

But If I try to check it at endpoint explorer, it shows toml empty -

```
"records": [
  {
    "_links": {
      "toml": {
        "href": ""
      }
    },
```

One more issue is, I don't see logo of the token on stellarterm, it shows UnKnown

Any idea what might be wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

It updates automatically after some time, no answers required :)

Comment: Could you give an approximate time-frame from your experience? Minutes, hours, days? Edit: nm, I was missing the CORS headers, updated immediately once set.

Comment: CORS need to be set and it does it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of setting the home domain on the account is to know where to fetch the `stellar.toml`.

The `/assets` endpoint should be updated within a few minutes on a Horizon instance that is already fully caught up to the network.